# Checking if table exist in database

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc

I have a `JDBC` code which retrieves data from database and get queries at runtime. At runtime, it will go to database and will try to get data and write it to a file. If table is not present it gives exception that table not found.  How to handle this?

Here I can not use,

```
ResultSet rs = md.getTable()
```

I have to check at runtime only.

SQL Example : `select * from table;` Preparedstatement and ResultSet here,

At runtime this table variable will get names of table when loop above this will iterate.  If table is not there then it gives this exception on console.

How to handle this smoothly?

Comment: Just show more codes. What is md? DatabaseMetaData? There is no `getTable` method, only `getTables`. Try `md.getTables(null, null, "<your_table_name>", null)`.

Comment: I am saying about getTables method only that I cannot use it

Comment: If you cannot use `DatabaseMetaData#getTables()`, then your only option is to catch the exception that will occur when you try to access the table.  Why are you not able to use `getTables()`?  Please [edit] your post and include ALL relevant information about your problem.

Comment: Edited question as said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dont want that exception, first you should check what tables are there in the database. If the table doesn't exist you can create and avoid that exception.

```
DatabaseMetaData dbm = con.getMetaData();
ResultSet tables = dbm.getTables(null, null, "your_table_name", null);
if (tables.next()) {
  // Table exists
}
else {
  // Table does not exist
}
```

if the table doesnot exist, you may need to create a new table to avoid such exception later.

Answer (score 0):

with `hsqlDB` you can do a `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS newTable (column details...)` if you only wanted to be sure before creating a new one.